# Link redirect to delete a query with PHP

Tags: php, hyperlink

Usually, when I need to delete a query, I don't know how to do it, I don't mean, I don't know the SQL code to do it. I mean I don't know the exactly way to "call" the function. The way I've found is to call the function via GET doing this:

```
<?php
   $action = $_GET['action'];
   $id = $_GET['id'];

   if($action == 'delete'){
      echo "This would to the query to delete the element";
   }
?>
```

So, The way I have to call it is by GET. I create a link with the next URI:

`http://localhost/test/index.php?action=delete&id=1`

This actually works. But I don't like how does it works. I don't like this way, and I am wondering if there's any other way to do exactly the same, with Javascript, JSON or even AJAX.

Comment: So.. what do you mean?

Comment: Generally it's a good practice to not accept delete requests from get.  Deletion and modification should happen via post.

Comment: "when I need to delete a query" - do you mean "when I need a delete query"?

Comment: Your application is vulnerable to a CSRF attack

Answer (score 2):

You tried to request the delete action by POST?
Send the id on a hidden text field like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="linkhere">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$idhere?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="actionnamehere">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

You can add some javascript with the confirm button too.
Using it u won't need to use the GET method and show on the URL these parameters.